# Furuno GP32 chartplotter with multiplexer bluetooth setup

Tags: bluetooth, gps

I have a couple of guys with [Furuno GP32's](http://www.furuno.com/en/products/chartplotter/GP-32) set up like this:

`GP32 <---> COMPUTER`

I'm looking for a way to insert a multiplexer, or some device in the middle that has the ability to broadcast NMEA data via bluetooth or wifi, so that it looks like this:

`GP32 <---> BLUETOOTH BROADCASTING DEVICE <---> COMPUTER`

The wiring info and the device info is [here](http://www.furuno.pl/fileadmin/files/Manuals/8_GPS_Plotter_ECDIS/GP-32/Old/GP-32-37_OM_ENG_44200G.pdf).

What solutions, or devices would allow me to do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your link to the "wiring info and the device info" is broken. It would be ideal to transpose that information directly into your posted question, for accessibility and to avoid "Link Rot": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot